# Terminology for path till class name in Java

Tags: java

Suppose, I've package `org.test.selenium` and class which is defined for it is `TestClass`. Then, what is the terminology for the path `org.test.selenium.TestClass` in Java?

Actually, I want to pass the variable which contains this path to a method and hence want to give correct name to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called as " fully qualified name of a class.

[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) mentioned as

> The fully qualified name of the `Rectangle` class in the graphics package is `graphics.Rectangle`, and the fully qualified name of the `Rectangle` class in the `java.awt` package is `java.awt.Rectangle`.

Answer (score 3):

It's commonly called the "Fully Qualified Class Name" (FQCN), and shows up as such in various online [acronym dictionaries](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=acronym+FQCN).

The [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html) mostly uses the terms "fully qualified name" or "canonical name" of a class, interface, type, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is called either the `fully qualified name` or the `canonical name` of the class (both are the same in this case since it is a top level class).

See [the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7)

If you want to pass exactly this name to a `String` parameter, you should do so using

```
TestClass.class.getName()
```